# Getting the sum of a count column

Tags: sql

I have a query which I use to get the number of nights that guests have stayed in a hotel room.

```
SELECT tm.RoomID,COUNT(tm.BookingID) AS [No Of Nights] FROM GuestRegistry tm
WHERE tm.RoomID IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY tm.BookingID,tm.RoomID
```

This is the result:

[image: Result is here]

How do I get the total of the number of nights column, i.e. 72.

Comment: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>  @*Included for the table*@





<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")

Answer (score 1):

```
With cte (roomid,NoOfNights) 
As
(
SELECT tm.RoomID,COUNT(tm.BookingID) AS [NoOfNights] 
FROM GuestRegistry tm WHERE tm.RoomID IS NOT NULL GROUP BY tm.BookingID,tm.RoomID
)
Select sum(NoOfNights) from CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

You could perform a sum of the result:

```
select sum([No Of Nights] ) from (
SELECT tm.RoomID,COUNT(tm.BookingID) AS [No Of Nights] 
FROM GuestRegistry  tm
WHERE tm.RoomID IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY tm.BookingID,tm.RoomID ) t
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        margin-left: 10pt;
        padding: 10pt;
    }

    .TimePickerWidth {
        width: 150px;
    }
</style>
```

$(document).ready(function () {

```
    GetReservationList();

    $("#btnAddUser").click(function () {

        var userID = 0;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("CreateEdit", "Employee")',
            dataType: "html",
            data: { userID: userID },
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#CheckOutModalBody").html(data);
                $("#CheckOutModal").modal("show");
            }
        });

    });

});

function onAddEditUserSuccess(data) {
    alert('success')
    //check if the method returns a Json object.
    if (typeof data == "object") {
        //if yes,then check if the status is Success or Not.
        if (data !== null && data.status != undefined && data.status === false) {

            ShowErrorModal("Error", data.message);
        } else {
            $("#CheckOutModal").modal("hide");
            GetReservationList();
        }
    } else {
        $("#CheckOutModalBody").html(data);
    }
}

function GetReservationList() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetEmployeeList", "Employee")',

        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        beforeSend: function () { },
        success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            if (response != undefined) {
                DisplayExpectedArrivalList(response);

            }
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(response.responseText);
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.responseText);
        }
    });
}


function DisplayExpectedArrivalList(data) {

    $('#propertyList').DataTable({
        "scrollX": true,
        destroy: true,
        "processing": true,
        "data": data,
        "oLanguage": {
            "sEmptyTable": "Sorry! No data found",
        },
        "columns": [
           { data: "LoginID" },
           { data: "Name" },

        { data: "password" }
        ],
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "render": function (data, type, row) {
                    var html = '<input type="button" id="btnEdit" onclick="AddEditUser(' + row.LoginID + ')" class="btn btn-primary bg-green" value="Edit" /> '+
                    '<input type="button" id="btnEdit" onclick="Delete(' + row.LoginID + ')" class="btn btn-primary bg-green" value="Delete" /> '
                    return html;
                },

                "targets": 3
            }
        ],



        "initComplete": function (settings, json) {
        },
        "fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {

        }
    });
}

function AddEditUser(LoginID) { alert('')

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '@Url.Action("CreateEdit", "Employee")',
        dataType: "html",
        data: { userID: LoginID },
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#CheckOutModalBody").html(data);
            $("#CheckOutModal").modal("show");

            GetReservationList();
        }
    });

}

function Delete(LoginID) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("DeleteUser", "Employee")',
        dataType: "html",
        data: { userID: LoginID },
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data !== null && data.status == 'successfully' && data.status === false) {
                alert('deleted');
            }
        }
    });

}

<button type="button" id="btnAddUser" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-bottom:10px">Add a new Employee</button>

<table id="propertyList" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                LoginID
            </th>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Password
            </th>
            <th>
                Actions
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>


</table>


<div class="modal fade" style="overflow-y: scroll;" id="CheckOutModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="file" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content" id="CheckOutModalBody">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```